# Why we using #ifdef DEBUG in iphone

Tags: iphone

thanks for sending me answer in advance....I m the beginner in IPhone.

I really excited why we using #ifdef DEBUG in iphone.Also wanting information about how to use it and its limitation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

a code in a

```
#ifdef DEBUG
//some code
#endif
```

is executed only in the debug builds. Why we use it? Because you can add some logging into the debug builds in order to get information about your performance or just anything else you want to know about your code.

Comment: It is not only in the debug builds, it is when `debug` is defined. So I could take the debug definition out of the debug configuration and put it into `Release` and `Distribution` configuration and the code would run in those builds and not the `debug` build. (Search for `Preprocessor Macros` in build settings).